# Prove that a solution of $y_{1}y_{3}=3y_{2}^{2}$ can be $x=A_{1}y+A_{2}$ and $x=A_{1}y^{2}+A_{2}y+A_{3}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, contest-math

**Q:**

> Prove that a solution of $y_{1}y_{3}=3y_{2}^{2}$ can be $x=A_{1}y+A_{2}$ and $x=A_{1}y^{2}+A_{2}y+A_{3}$, where $y_{n}=\frac{d^{n}y}{dx^{n}}$

**Approach:**

> Firstly, differentiating both sides:
> $$y_{2}y_{3}+y_{1}y_{4}=6y_{2}y_{3}\to y_{1}y_{4}=5y_{2}y_{3}$$
> Let $$y_{1}=t,\ y_{3}=z$$
> Thus, $$y_{2}=\frac{dt}{dx},\ y_{4}=\frac{dz}{dx}$$
> We have $$t\cdot\frac{dz}{dx}=5\cdot\frac{dt}{dx}\cdot z\to\int_{ }^{ }\frac{dz}{z}=5\cdot\int_{ }^{ }\frac{dt}{t}$$
> $$z=k\cdot t^{5}$$

But I don't know how to proceed further, where am I going wrong? Please answer in a simple way, I am a high school student.

Comment: Instead of differentiating, divide both sides by $y_1y_2$ and your answer becomes almost immediate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y$ is a linear function of $x$, then $y_2=y_3=0$. Therefore it is a solution of the DE.

---

In the other case, simply divide both sides of the equation by $y_1y_2$

$$\frac{y_3}{y_2} = \frac{3y_2}{y_2} \implies y_2 = -2A_1y_1^3$$

Then divide both sides by $y_1^2$

$$\frac{y_2}{y_1^2} = -2A_1y_1 \implies \frac{1}{y_1} = 2A_1y+A_2$$

or

$$x = A_2y^2+A_2y+A_3$$